# Wait N Seconds to Do Something, When User Tap During This period, Cancel it

Tags: android

I want to achieve the following task:

```
if (already wait for 3 seconds) {
    // do the task
} else {
    // keep waiting ...
    if (user tap the UI widget) {
        return; // do nothing
    }
}
```

At first, I want to use handler, use `sendMessageDelayed` (Message msg, long delayMillis) to enqueue a message into the message queue after all pending messages before (current time + delayMillis). when the user taps, I `removeMessages`(int what). But it does not work.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thanks.

========================================================

Thanks all.

I found this solution works well, I was too careless to use the wrong Handler reference to `removeMessages`, so, it did not work.

Comment: The approach you outlined seems like it should work. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Dear @Squonk, "Sth" is short for "something", to make it clear, I have changed it to "something"

Comment: hi, @TedHopp, thanks for your tip, it always works fine. I just used the wrong reference of the Handler.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the plain old Java API [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [ScheduledFuture](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html):

```
// This schedule a runnable task in 3 seconds:
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    doSomethingUseful();
  }
}, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

... ...

// some times later if user tap the screen:
if (user tap the UI widget) {
  if (!scheduledFuture.isDone())
    scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. Actually, I found my first solution works well. It was my careless that did not found it at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag when the user taps, and when the handler message is received, check that flag.

You could also use a Timer, schedule a TimerTask, and cancel the task when the user taps.